# SQL Query - Querying from 3 Tables with ID Order

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to export records based on the following tables below.

**de_orders** (date_add is order created)

```
id_order  |   id_carrier  |        date_add  
    5     |        1      |    2017-10-24 09:14:51
    6     |        2      |    2017-10-25 10:14:51
    7     |        3      |    2017-10-26 08:14:51
```

**de_order_history**

```
id_order  |   id_order_state |        date_add
    5     |        2         |   2017-10-24 10:14:51
    5     |        3         |   2017-10-24 11:14:51
    5     |        4         |   2017-10-24 12:14:51
```

**de_carrier**

```
    id_carrier  |   name  
        1       |   XXX
        2       |   YYY
        3       |   ZZZ
```

I am able to get only one date at the moment as such.

```
id_order  |  id_carrier |  date_add(from orders) | date_add (from id_order_state (4))
    5     |     XXX     |   2017-10-24 09:14:51  |       2017-10-24 12:14:51
```

With the query below:

```
SELECT
o.id_order AS ID,
o.date_add AS Order_date,
h.date_add AS Delivered_date,
c.name AS carrier_name
FROM de_orders o
LEFT JOIN de_order_history h ON (o.id_order=h.id_order)
LEFT JOIN de_carrier c ON (o.id_carrier=c.id_carrier)
WHERE  YEAR(o.date_add) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(o.date_add) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
AND h.id_order_state="4"
GROUP BY o.id_order
ORDER BY o.id_order
```

I would like to export the following:

**Desired Results (Return all records WHERE id_order_state = 4)**

```
id_order  |  id_carrier |  date_add(from orders) | date_add (from id_order_state (3)) | date_add (from id_order_state (4))
    5     |     XXX     |   2017-10-24 09:14:51  |       2017-10-24 11:14:51          |        2017-10-24 12:14:51
```

Am I looking at it the wrong way?

Thank you.

Comment: *Desired Results (Return all records WHERE id_order_state = 4)* ... only one record has this condition: id_order = 5. How does calculated column, *date_add (from id_order_state (3))* match any criteria?

Comment: Yes, I am lost on setting a condition to fulfil a return as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a conditional aggregate by moving *id_order_state* `WHERE` condition into an inline `CASE` statement. Also, your `GROUP BY` now includes *Order_date* to be syntatically correct with SQL ANSI where non-aggregated columns must be included in `GROUP BY`: clause:

```
SELECT o.id_order AS ID, 
       c.`name` AS ID_Carrier,
       o.date_add AS Order_date, 
       MAX(CASE 
                WHEN h.id_order_state='3' 
                THEN h.date_add 
           END) AS ID_Order_State_3_Deliver_date,
       MAX(CASE 
                WHEN h.id_order_state='4' 
                THEN h.date_add 
           END) AS ID_Order_State_4_Deliver_date,
       c.name AS carrier_name
FROM de_orders o
LEFT JOIN de_order_history h ON (o.id_order=h.id_order)
LEFT JOIN de_carrier c ON (o.id_carrier=c.id_carrier)
WHERE YEAR(o.date_add) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
  AND MONTH(o.date_add) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)     
GROUP BY o.id_order, c.`name`, o.date_add
ORDER BY o.id_order, c.`name`, o.date_add
```

Comment: I will take note the condition that I can place in MAX(CASE .... END) AS .... I have never used inline case statements previously. Thank you for your advice and sample code, it has helped me solved my problem.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Yes `CASE` can be wrapped in aggregates and helps in conditional assignment of columns.